# Add fields from another form to a existing form in a widget

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to build a module that provides a widget. 
The widget is based on `FileWidget` and I would like to add some fields from another form to the existing `FileWidget` form.
I would like to save the content of these fields after submit of the parent form.

So I loaded the form, from which I want to add some elements, in my widgets process method, with 
`\Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity)` but I am having troubles extracting specific field elements.
If I add a new form element, let's say a textfield, it works as intended and I can access the user input of this field in `hook_entity_presave`, but sadly not with elements from an existing form.

In Drupal 7 this could be done with the function `field_attach_form()` but this is not possible anymore.

Is there a clean way in Drupal 8 for this?

Comment: Hey @tobyte, did you find a solution?

Comment: Actually I did, I ended up using the EntityFormDisplay like this:
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/tobytes/67a2c1fa9dfb78a2ce7f5a65b44c58c9)